# Slicing string in list python using a separator python

Tags: python, list

Is it possible to slice a string in a list using a separator?

When I use `sep = ":"` and try to slice I get an error saying that slicing is only possible with number indexing. I'd like to slice each string on the `:` separator.

```
['Brandon:5', 'Patrick:18.9', 'Brandon:xyz', 'Jack:', 'Sarah:825', 'Jack:45', 'Brandon:10', 'James:3.25', 'James:125.62', 'Sarah:2.43', 'Brandon:100.5']
```

---

```
text2 =  ['Brandon:5', 'Patrick:18.9', 'Brandon:xyz', 'Jack:', 'Sarah:825', 'Jack:45', 'Brandon:10', 'James:3.25', 'James:125.62', 'Sarah:2.43', 'Brandon:100.5']

sep = ':'

text3 = [w[:sep] for w in text2]
```

Output:

```
TypeError: slice indices must be integers or None or have an __index__ method
```

Comment: Please include your code and the complete error traceback in your question.

Comment: What's the expected output?

Comment: Expected output is to append 2 lists. 1 with names and the second one with the value after the separator :

Comment: Please share the code you've written so far, in its entirety.

Answer (score 3):

You can split each string in a list comprehension with [`str.split()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.split). This will give you a list of lists. You can than [zip](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip) this and unpack it into separate lists:

```
l = ['Brandon:5', 'Patrick:18.9', 'Brandon:xyz', 'Jack:', 'Sarah:825', 'Jack:45', 'Brandon:10', 'James:3.25', 'James:125.62', 'Sarah:2.43', 'Brandon:100.5']

names, data = zip(*(s.split(':') for s in l))
```

`names` will be:

```
('Brandon',
 'Patrick',
 'Brandon',
 'Jack',
 'Sarah',
 'Jack',
 'Brandon',
 'James',
 'James',
 'Sarah',
 'Brandon')
```

and `data` will be:

`('5', '18.9', 'xyz', '', '825', '45', '10', '3.25', '125.62', '2.43', '100.5')`

Answer (score 1):

## UPDATE

The reason your code throws an error is because you'll need to pass the *index* of the character as the slices, and the characters themselves:

```
text2 =  ['Brandon:5', 'Patrick:18.9', 'Brandon:xyz', 'Jack:', 'Sarah:825', 'Jack:45', 'Brandon:10', 'James:3.25', 'James:125.62', 'Sarah:2.43', 'Brandon:100.5']

sep = ':'

text3 = [w[:w.index(sep)] for w in text2]
text4 = [w[w.index(sep):] for w in text2]
```

---

*Mark Meyer's solution is optimal, but not very beginner friendly.*

Here is a step by step procedure:

1. We have the this list:

```
['Brandon:5', 'Patrick:18.9', 'Brandon:xyz', 'Jack:', 'Sarah:825', 'Jack:45', 'Brandon:10', 'James:3.25', 'James:125.62', 'Sarah:2.43', 'Brandon:100.5']
```

Let's assign it to a variable so that we can access it later in the program:

```
lst = ['Brandon:5', 'Patrick:18.9', 'Brandon:xyz', 'Jack:', 'Sarah:825', 'Jack:45', 'Brandon:10', 'James:3.25', 'James:125.62', 'Sarah:2.43', 'Brandon:100.5']
```

2. Define two lists, `names` and `numbers` to later store the retrieved names and numbers.

```
names = []
numbers = []
```

3. Iterate through the `lst` list, and split each string at the `":"`:

```
for s in lst:
    s.split(":")
```

4. Now, assign the two values in the `s.split(":")` list into two variables, `name` and `number`:

```
name, number = s.split(":")
```

5. Finally, append the strings into the two lists created eariler:

```
names.append(name)
numbers.append(number)
```

Altogether:

```
lst = ['Brandon:5', 'Patrick:18.9', 'Brandon:xyz', 'Jack:', 'Sarah:825', 'Jack:45', 'Brandon:10', 'James:3.25', 'James:125.62', 'Sarah:2.43', 'Brandon:100.5']
names = []
numbers = []
for s in lst:
    name, number = s.split(":")
    names.append(name)
    numbers.append(number)
print(names)
print(numbers)
```

Output:

```
['Brandon', 'Patrick', 'Brandon', 'Jack', 'Sarah', 'Jack', 'Brandon', 'James', 'James', 'Sarah', 'Brandon']
['5', '18.9', 'xyz', '', '825', '45', '10', '3.25', '125.62', '2.43', '100.5']
```